# Filter the pyspark dataframe based on values in list

Tags: python, pyspark

I am fairly new to pyspark. I have pyspark dataframe which has information about number of times a particular person has got message from a brand. It has three columns `id`, `brand` and `count`, as show below.

```
|  id |  brand  | Count |
|:---:|:-------:|:-----:|
| 143 |  AD-ABC |   3   |
| 314 | AX-DEFG |   8   |
| 381 |  AD-ABC |   6   |
| 425 | AD-XYZP |   7   |
| 432 |  AD-GAF |   8   |
| 102 |  AD-GAF |   1   |
| 331 |  AX-ABC |   10  |
| 191 |  AD-GAF |   9   |
| 224 |  AD-GAF |   6   |
```

The brand column is bit complex and I want to derive new column `brand2` from brand column as shown below(keep character after -)

```
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
| id  |  brand  | Count | brand2 |
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
| 143 | AD-ABC  |     3 | ABC    |
| 314 | AX-DEFG |     8 | DEFG   |
| 381 | AD-ABC  |     6 | ABC    |
| 425 | AD-XYZP |     7 | XYZP   |
| 432 | AD-GAF  |     8 | GAF    |
| 102 | AD-GAF  |     1 | GAF    |
| 331 | AX-ABC  |    10 | ABC    |
| 191 | AD-GAF  |     9 | GAF    |
| 224 | AD-GAF  |     6 | GAF    |
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
```

I have a very large list which has the brands that I want to filter out from the dataframe as below

`brand_subset = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZP']  #The list is very large !!`

The desired dataframe which I want is as below

```
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
| id  |  brand  | Count | brand2 |
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
| 143 | AD-ABC  |     3 | ABC    |
| 381 | AD-ABC  |     6 | ABC    |
| 425 | AD-XYZP |     7 | XYZP   |
| 331 | AX-ABC  |    10 | ABC    |
+-----+---------+-------+--------+
```

The above is just a sample scenario, practically both the list and the table is very large.

Any help will be appreciated. (It will be good if the solution is optimized considering size of database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the brand column and get the second element, then use `isin` to check if `brand2` is in the list:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
brand_subset = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZP']

(df.withColumn("brand2",F.split("brand","-")[1]).where(F.col("brand2")
                                          .isin(brand_subset))).show()
```

or:

```
(df.withColumn("brand2",F.split("brand","-")[1]).filter(F.col("brand2")
                                            .isin(brand_subset)).show()
```

---

```
+---+-------+-----+------+
| id|  brand|Count|brand2|
+---+-------+-----+------+
|143| AD-ABC|    3|   ABC|
|381| AD-ABC|    6|   ABC|
|425|AD-XYZP|    7|  XYZP|
|331| AX-ABC|   10|   ABC|
+---+-------+-----+------+
```